# I am creating a horizontal list of months for a fixed size the list is overlapping

Tags: css, html

This is the <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/juc6P/)**</kbd>  and correct me

HTML

```
<div id = "container">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" > JANUARY </a> </li>
     <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> FEBURAY </a> </li>
     <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" > MARCH </a> </li> 
     <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> APRIL </a> </li>
     <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> MAY  </a> </li>
     <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> JUNE </a> </li>
     <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> AUGUST</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"> SEPTEMBER</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#container {
    width: 550px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    border: 2px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding: .8em 0.5em;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 35%;
    margin-left:5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#container ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #369;
}
```

Comment: You should include any relevant information in the question. Not only a fiddle link.

Comment: How you want it to behave? I mean giving a fixed width and height to container will result in what you are observing.

Comment: Actually i have to display the months onclick of the navigation buttons at a time we have to dispaly 5 months.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/juc6P/3/

make the following changes in the css

```
#container
{
    width: 550px;  
    background: blue;
    border: 2px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*either remove height from here so that its set to auto or increase the width*/
}

#container ul li { 
    display:inline-block;
    /*det display property to inline block*/
    padding: .8em 0.5em;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 35%;
    margin-left:5px;
   text-decoration: none;    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following adjustment to your CSS file.

```
 #container {
    width: 550px;
    background: blue;
    border: 2px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Hear I have removed fixed height of the #container.

```
#container ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: .8em 0.5em;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 35%;
    margin-left:5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

change the line-height to adjust the height of the row.